# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I have a very simply program that I copied from Google's workspaces, the import statements are as follows

```
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
```

When I run this code, I keep getting:

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

I have been through every question on the topic here, pip installed the world and still no love.  I created a requirements.txt file and used pip show to obtained the current versions that ARE installed in my C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\ - which is in my PATH along with C:\Python310\ and C:\Python310\Scripts.

```
openai==1.14.0
langchain==0.1.12
streamlit==1.32.2
google==3.0.0
google-auth==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.4.0
google_auth_oauthlib==1.2.0
oauthlib==3.2.2
google-api-python-client==2.122.0
```

The requirements document, in VSCode, shows no missing references and yet I keep getting the same error.  I even went through VSCode Intellisense and manually recreated each Import statement with no issues.  So VSCode sees the modules but I still get that same error.

Can somebody possibly help me out?

Thank you for your time.

***UPDATE: Complete code sample****

```
# Imports
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


# Authenticate
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=10).execute()
```

Comment: what api are you trying to connect to exactly? Copying someone else's code without understanding its not a really good way to start.  Can I see the full example you are using?

Comment: I understand the code - it is the module that is the issue.  I have tried a TON of examples - I just added one above.

Comment: Yes but if i know the api i can point you directly at the quickstart for that api if i dont personally have on.  Note thats not enough auth code to work. You may want to check the official sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions that you should try.

1. Verify that the site-packages directory where the required packages are installed is included in your PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can do this by printing `sys.path` in your Python script to see which directories Python searches for packages.
2. Double-check that the required packages (google, google-auth, google-auth-oauthlib, google-api-python-client) are installed in the correct site-packages directory. You can use `pip list` to see the installed packages and their versions.

Comment: Thanks - I had Python310 on my main C Drive for the VSCode install and I never realized it was there until I saw your note.  As soon as I removed it, the Version was correct and the code ran!

Answer (score 0):

My samples all use

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

Think you are missing google-auth-httplib2

This is also shown in the official sample for Gmail [install_the_google_client_library](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#install_the_google_client_library)

Comment: I ended up downloading PyCharm, opened up the project and it installed google-auth-httplib2 just like you said.  Thank you!

Comment: I use PyCharm to never managed to get VsCode to work.